# cannot verify the contract address because of compiler version 0.4.9 not available in etherscan verify contract

Tags: solidity, etherscan, contract-verification

My compiler version is solidity 0.4.9, but i am not able to verify my contract address on etherscan verify contract, the reason is 0.4.9 is not in the list compilers...please tell me the solution to verify the contract.[image: ether scan verify contract]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you just deployed this contract recently. I would suggest upgrading your compiler to the latest (0.5.10 at the time of this post) or at least the latest 0.4.x compiler and redeploying. Not only will you be able to verify your contract code on Etherscan, but you won't be subjected to all the compiler bugs that existed in those old versions.

Comment: i have just changed the compiler version to 0.4.11 and it gives some warning, but working fine after deployment.
Thanks